# JQuery Two 'Select All' Checkboxes Across 2 Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two tables that are filled with a number of checkboxes (the number is variable based on a retrieval profile defined on a previous screen).  I've implemented a Select All check box at the top of each table with the following:

```
    $('#select_all').bind('click', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
        });
    } else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
 });
```

But this function selects all checkboxes in both tables (as it is poorly written to do).    Is there an easy method of having the code select all checkboxes in each distinct tables.

Thanks.

Comment: We need the HTML too. You need to post a [mcve]. And one hint, `$(':checkbox')` is selecting too many things.

Comment: I don't think we even need the html here, you can spot the issue just from his js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your css more selective. It may not be necessary to use ids and an entirely different click function for each. You can probably just have a single click function bound to both and use the right selector, but hard to know without seeing your html.

If you post your html it will make it easier to help you, but you need something like the following:

```js
$('#select_all1').bind('click', function() {
  var checkedState = this.checked;
  $('#table1 :checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = checkedState;
  });
});

$('#select_all2').bind('click', function() {
  var checkedState = this.checked;
  $('#table2 :checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = checkedState;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all1"></input>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" id="select_all2"></input>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just to add that a modified version of this worked.  Apologies for not posting the HTML in the first instance but this example wasn't far off what was required anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable you use class attribute for your table since Id's are supposed to be unique.

Create a variable to store value for table closest to checkbox current checkbox triggered and Concatenate the variable with Selector.

```js
$('.selectAll').bind('click', function() {
  var thisTable = $(this).closest('.checkTable');//closest table of this checkbox triggered
  var checkedState = this.checked;//variable for checkbox checked.
  $(':checkbox', thisTable).each(function(){//concatenate 'thisTable' variable with css selector and iterate
    this.checked = checkedState;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="checkTable">
  <tr>
    <th> <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll"></th>
    <th>Select All</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="1"></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="2"></td>
    <td>Hi</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<table class="checkTable">
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" class="selectAll"></th>
    <th>Select All</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="3"></td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="4"></td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use different id for different table or use class for table instead of id like so:

```
$('.select_all').bind('click', function() {
if(this.checked) {
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
    });
} else {
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
    });
}
});
```